# How to send cookies in an Image() constructor

Tags: javascript, image, cookies

I'm injecting an image into a canvas that I have to get securely by passing cookies with my request. My issue is that the Image constructor doesn't seem to send the cookies with the request when the src is set. The cookies are not accessible through js, they are sent by the browser.

```
var img = new Image();
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

validateUrl(originalUrl, function (validatedUrl) {
    img.src = validatedUrl; //GET fails after this happens
});

img.onload = function () {
   drawImageProp(context, img);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `crossorigin` attribute on an image, then cookies are not sent with the request for the image.  That's how that feature is written to work.

Cookies are tied to a specific domain/subdomain (and optionally to a path within that domain).  When requesting an image, any cookies for the domain that the image is being requested from will be automatically sent with the image request.

The browser only gives Javascript access to cookies that are in the same origin as the host web page.  So, Javascript has no ability to read cookies for some other domain.

So, when you request your image by setting the `.src` property, any cookies that belong to the domain of the image URL will be sent with the image request automatically (you don't do anything to cause that).

Comment: When i put the url into an <img> tag, it shows up fine - in that case inspecting the network calls i can see that the cookies are going with the request. In this case though, the server gives me an error because it didn't get the cookies, and I'm trying to figure out why they're not going. The request isn't even going cross-domain in this case.

Comment: @TanyaMounitsyna - I ran my own tests in a jsFiddle and cookies are sent when I create an image manually.  So, I'm not sure how to reproduce your issue.  In my test, I had to add a random query parameter to the end of the URL just to defeat the image cache in order to test.  Are you sure you're not having caching issues?

Comment: @TanyaMounitsyna - If you set the `crossorigin` attribute on an image, then cookies are not sent with the request.  That's how that feature is written to work.  See the description by "anonymous" here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-crossorigin